# Alternator amperage to charge 3 batteries

Tags: honda, battery, alternator, accord, charging

I have a 2009 accord sedan, with a sound system installed. How many amps should my alternator be to charge my 3 batteries? My OEM alternator currently puts out 130.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Need the details of your batteries for a start.

Comment: I have one optima yellow top under the hood, and 2 XS leasure batteries in trunk.

Comment: 5 amps will charge 3 batteries (very slow), so your 130 amp should have no problems. Generally you only need a larger alternator if you are running big amplifiers or air bag pumps/ hydraulic systems added to your car.